# Is there way of querying to jsonb column with some conditions in "value array" in postgresql?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, jsonb

I'm a new beginner at Postgresql. And I'm looking for a way to make a query to meet the condition.

I've tried to make a query to find some data in jsonb column, but failed. Below is my sample case.

- column name : data
- column type : jsonb
- sample data

```
{"id": "1", "ips": [3232238180, 3232238181]}
{"id": "1", "ips": [{"ip": 3232238180}, {"ip": 3232238181}]}
```

There are some IPs as an integer in "ips" array.
I want to find rows that have specific integer IPs using range query(ex: "ip" in 192.168.10.0/24)

I know I can find the rows if the data form was like (2).

```
select * 
from table_name, 
     JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(data->'ips') ips 
where (ips->>'ip')::NUMERIC > xxxxxx 
  and (ips->>'ip')::NUMERIC < xxxxxx
```

Nevertheless, I'm wondering I can find it in (1) type.
Because I think (1) type has some benefit of saving storage.
Is there anyone who knows about it?

Comment: The difference between (1) and (2) is just dropping the `->>'ip'` from `ips`.

Comment: If you want to save storage, don't store the ips as an array of "integers" in a jsonb column in the first place. Use an [`inet[]`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-net-types.html) [array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) column.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you for the reply. Yes, you might be right. If the IPs are able to be stored as an inet value, it would be better. But I have some reasons for what I should store by json type. My data cannot normalize because of dynamic source logs.

Comment: @Bergi Anyway, I think I should save data as a type (2).    
I read [this document](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE), and I could not find out the way of comparing my conditions with values in the array, such as 'like', 'between' query.

Comment: What postgres version are you using? [JsonPath](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) would be the perfect tool, but of course if you cast the json values you can also use `LIKE` and `BETWEEN`